# How to create a transparent png/gif in python of text

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to create a picture of text to watermark on a video for security purposes.

How would I create a png or gif in python of a string of text, for example "mark@gmail.com". Is there a way to do this with PIL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about with PIL but I imagine the [png](http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html) library can do this.

There's also [this](http://jtauber.com/blog/2008/05/18/creating_gradients_programmatically_in_python/) which doesn't use any module but directly writes to the png. The format is very clean and so you can probably customise this to create a transparent png. Writing the text on it is another question.

Another option is to shell out and use imagemagick's "convert" tool.